# How can i find number of ways presenting number as sum of no more than 4 squares

Tags: sums-of-squares, dynamic-programming, lagrange-interpolation

I am given a number and I have to find number of ways to present that number as sum of no more than 4 squares.For example $25$ can be presented as $1^2+2^2+2^2+4^2$, $3^2+4^2$ and $5^2$.

Comment: Jacobi's theorem does not refer to ordered positive representations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem#Number_of_representations

Answer (score 0):

I would start with $n_1$, which can be represented in exactly one way ($1=1^2$) and try to come up with a recurrence of how to compute $n_{k+1}$ if all of $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ are available.

Comment: I'm stuck at coming up with a solution of computing nk+1 when n1 is available.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem#Number_of_representations